# Why in Blender 2.7 many vertex group functions are "not yet implemented"?

Tags: python, vertex-groups

how to contact developers?
Anyway, i found a simple solution e.g. for selecting vertices that belongs to a vertexgroup

```
def selgv (groupname):
"""selgv(groupname) -> Select vertices of active object by groupname given"""
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
obj = bpy.context.active_object
for group in obj.vertex_groups:
    if group.name == groupname:
        for vertex in bpy.data.meshes[obj.name].vertices:
            for g in vertex.groups:
                if g.group == group.index:
                    vertex.select=True
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
```

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you are asking here. Can you add a bit more to the post.

Comment: I'm using blender 2.70 for skinning mi models. When i want to work with VERTEX_GROUPS, clicking on them under the mesh groups menu, and i want to select vertices of a vertex group or anything else, it says "not yet implemented", i proposed i an example of how it can be done

Comment: Oh, this is a question and answer site. To reach a developer, you can try `#blendercoders` on irc on the freenode network or over at http://developer.blender.org

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  I'm using the latest release, and all the menu options for selecting vertices work just fine.  Doing it in python is more difficult, but possible as you showed.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, i tried to select vertices of a vertexgroup from the outliner...